# FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification on Print to File case

Tags: c++, winapi, printing

I am trying to monitor the jobs on a remote spooler. I am using the code below for this. When actually printing something, MyChangeCallback is called and I can proceed normally. However, if I tick "Print to File" box on the print dialog my callback is never called. Any ideas how to make it work even if the "Print to File" is selected?

```
// Callback definition

VOID MyChangeCallback(PVOID lpParameter, BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired)
{
   DEBUG("Change notification received");

   HANDLE hChange = *((HANDLE*)lpParameter));

   // Call FindNextPrinterChangeNotification with hChange
   ...
}


int main() {

    HANDLE hPrinter = 0;

    OpenPrinter(L"\\MyPrintServer\\SharedPrinter", &hPrinter, NULL);

    HANDLE hChange = FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification(   hPrinter,  
                                                           PRINTER_CHANGE_ALL, 
                                                           0, 
                                                           NULL);

    HANDLE hNewWaitObj = 0;

    RegisterWaitForSingleObject(    &hNewWait, 
                                    hChange, 
                                    MyChangeCallback,  
                                    (PVOID)&hChange, 
                                    INFINITE, 
                                    WT_EXECUTEDEFAULT);

    // Wait for events

    Sleep(INFINITE);
}
```

Comment: \\MyPrintServer\\SharedPrinter should be \\\\MyPrintServer\\SharedPrinter Also you probably need to call OpenPrinter2 with the option to bypass the cache. Finally you need to make sure you have the correct DesiredAccess in the PRINTER_DEFAULTS structure.